# HIVE Create table for JSON - STRUCT Error

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

I am trying to load JSON data to HIVE. I am using the default SERDE present in HIVE. I am encountering an error during create table. Help required!

**JSON data:**

```
{"widget": {
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    },
    "image": { 
        "src": "Images/Sun.png",
        "name": "sun1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 250,
        "alignment": "center"
    }
}}
```

**The Create Statement :**

```
CREATE TABLE complex_json(
widget struct<window:struct< title:string,name:string,width:int,height:int>,
debug:string,
image:struct< src:string,name:string,hOffset:int,vOffset:int,alignment:string > >
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe';
```

**And I am getting the error** :

> ParseException line 2:27 cannot recognize input near 'window' ':' 'struct' in column specification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WINDOW** is a reserved key word in Hive and directly you cannot use reserved as part of your column,[reserved key words](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Keywords,Non-reservedKeywordsandReservedKeywords)

You have two options here:

1.) Do not use any reserved key work as part of columns. Try renaming your object name from **window** to say **window1** and it will work.

2.) If you want to use keywords then use like this **`window`**, back quote and the column(key word)
So your create table will look like :

```
CREATE TABLE complex_json(
widget struct< `window` :struct< title:string,name:string,width:int,height:int>,
debug:string,
image:struct< src:string,name:string,hOffset:int,vOffset:int,alignment:string > >
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe';
```

Also make sure your JSON is in single line. All these SerDes don't recognize proper formatted JSON.

Hope it helps...!!!